# Javascript bookmarklet go to URL and execute

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a javascript like this, used i a bookmarklet:

```
window.location="URL"
document.getElementById('username-id').value = 'User'
document.getElementById('pwd-id').value = 'pass'
doLogin();
```

The problem is that javascript stops as soon as it hits the URL.
How to make it go to a page and execute a script?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately your bookmarklet will not work. Change of `window.location` results loading of the new page - you cannot execute any Javascript on that page without having the document present first.

The desired action can be achieved by browser extensions, e.g. Greasemonkey script, which execute specified Javascript on the page upon page load.

Answer (score 20):

I don't recommend browser extensions - they allow untrusted code to run in the context of trusted code. If you have a browser extension that loads a page and automatically enters your userID and password, what stops it from posting those credentials to a malicious site? Only you, and only if you've carefully read the source code.

To solve the problem above I've added bookmarklets to the favorites bar in my browser that require two clicks: 
 1. Click to navigate to the location
 2. Click to fill the form

```
javascript: 
 var L='http://mysite.com/';
 if(location!=L)location=L;
 else{
  document.getElementById('username-id').value='User'; 
  document.getElementById('pwd-id').value = 'pass';
  document.close();
  doLogin(); 
 }
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you control the page you're loading, I would consider passing that data as the fragment and handling that from the page. Something like `window.location="URL#username=...;password=..."`, than parsing the data from the fragment in the page and doing whatever you need with it. However, in this specific case its not a good idea as the password will be saved in the browsing history.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the bookmarklet from a page loaded on the same domain (and with the same scheme) as your target location, you can do it (sort of) by loading it into an iframe.

```
javascript:
document.body.innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://example.com/page2.html" onload="this.contentWindow.location.assign(`javascript:
    document.body.style.textTransform = \'uppercase\'; /* put code here */
void(0);`); this.onload = null;" width=100% height=100%>';
```

Note the use of back ticks for a multi-line string for legibility. The `onload = null` is required to prevent an infinite loop, as `onload` will fire after the location is assigned javascript code.

(Only tested in Chrome.)

Answer (score -2):

Try wrapping your code with `window.onload` event.

```
window.location = "URL"; window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('username-id').value = 'User'
document.getElementById('pwd-id').value = 'pass'
doLogin();
}
```

---

As the solution above doesn't work, you still should be able to write a simple browser extension to solve your problem. It's easy: choose the browser you use and follow the documentation. This is only way to do that.

Comment: Already tried it, still no luck. The script just goes to the page and stops.

Comment: Then, you need to write a browser extension to solve your problem, because bookmarklets are not so powerful in this case.

Comment: it won't work. new page = new script. can't run a script in a different page that it's declared in.