# How can I disable this popup using a Bookmarklet or Browser Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bookmarklet

Navigate to the following page:

https://www.business.hsbc.co.uk/1/2/bib/username

In their infinite wisdom HSBC have decided to pester their customers with this anti-virus program (Rapport) ad every time the online banking login screen is accessed. Any reason not to download the software is never persisted, making this repetitive process [infuriating for millions of UK HSBC customers](http://www.ukbusinessforums.co.uk/threads/dear-hsbc-no-i-dont-want-rapport.310469/).

I was wondering if it is possible to write a **bookmarklet** to load the page and hide the div using a timeout?

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to execute the script in the `setTimeout` block.

```
javascript:if(window.location!="https://www.business.hsbc.co.uk/1/2/bib/username"){window.location="https://www.business.hsbc.co.uk/1/2/bib/username"};
javascript:(window.setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("rap_wrapper").style.display = "none"; }, 1000));void(0);
```

`rap_wrapper` is the only element that needs to be removed in the DOM. The `setTimeout` is there to give sufficient time for the page to load. But I think this approach is sub-optimum as fire too early on slow connections.
Is there anyway I can use Chrome debugging tools to find the exact function that opens the modal box and kill it there?

Perhaps this is going a little beyond the scope of a simple bookmarklet, so would be happy to write a Chrome Extension instead. Just really trying to understand the best approach at this stage.

**EDIT 1:**

Bookmarklet is not going to work for this job as the `location.href` change will terminate any code that follows ([see post here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103996/javascript-bookmarklet-go-to-url-and-execute)). So I'm guessing a Chrome Extension it is, certainly will be easier, was just looking for a quick and dirty hack.

Comment: If the problem is really as simple as hiding the element, just use CSS: `#rap_wrapper {display:none !important;}`

Comment: Is it possible to manipulate css rules in a bookmarklet? I think onload it is actually in `display:none` state, some JS is revealing it immediately after.

Comment: Yes, just create a `<style>` tag, set its `textContent` to the CSS rules and insert the element in the document.

Comment: Unfortunately my Bookmarklet approach is not going to work due to the initial `location.href` change (see EDIT 1). Chrome Extension will allow me to do what you suggest, thanks for the help!

Comment: As long as the result is void, i.e. `undefined`, then the page will not unload. Though an extension is easier to use.